# WPF Architecture & Creating Unique Builds

Tags: wpf, architecture, build-automation

I haven't figured out the correct programming architecture for:
-WPF Application
-Each build will be unique for each customer
-There will be unique variables for each customer in both code and the app.config file
-Ideally, there will also be unique deployment URLs for each customer

What is the best way to build the project file given this scenario? Im using VS 2008 Pro. I can create all of the above and use ClickOnce for deployment, but its the unique variables for each customer that I need help with.

Comment: How many customers?
Is this a stand-alone deployment thing that's given to the client, or something that's accessed online / SaaS style?

Comment: For the purposes of the question, let's say its 5 different clients and its something that will be pushed out via the VS-native ClickOnce tools. It does have a SaaS component to it, but that's after it's installed. Again, I'm really only concerned with the build & ClickOnce deployment - each one needs to have some unique variables attached with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not 100% exactly what I need, but it's close. This article has an explanation of how to work with multiple config files and assign one during the pre-build process. It still doesn't allow me to set pieces of code like I would like, but it's almost close enough: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ManagingMultipleConfigurationFileEnvironmentsWithPreBuildEvents.aspx